# Salesforce Selector layer - subquery

Tags: query, fflib

We have been using FF library for Separation of Concerns framework and it is working great. We need to add subquery to it, but running into issues. Example I am following is from this article: https://quirkyapex.com/2016/08/18/fflib-selector-layer/

```
public class OpportunityLineItemsSelector extends fflib_SObjectSelector {

   public Schema.SObjectType getSObjectType(){
      return OpportunityLineItem.sObjectType;
   }

   public override List<Schema.SObjectField> getSObjectFieldList(){
      return new List<Schema.SObjectField> {
         OpportunityLineItem.Id,
         OpportunityLineItem.Quantity,
         OpportunityLineItem.SalesPrice
      };
   }

}

public class OpportunitiesSelector extends fflib_SObjectSelector {

   public Schema.SObjectType getSObjectType(){
      return Opportunity.sObjectType;
   }

   public override List<Schema.SObjectField> getSObjectFieldList(){
      return new List<Schema.SObjectField> {
         Opportunity.Id,
         Opportunity.StageName
      };
   }

   public List<Opportunity> selectByIdWithLineItems(Set<Id> recordIds){
      fflib_QueryFactory query = newQueryFactory();
      query.setCondition('Id IN :recordIds');
      query.addQueryFactorySubselect( 
         new OpportunityLineItemsSelector().newQueryFactory() 
      );
      return (List<Opportunity>) Database.query( query.toSOQL() );
   }

}
```

I get compile error:

> Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void addQueryFactorySubselect(fflib_QueryFactory) from the type fflib_QueryFactory at line 17 column 13

Below method does exist in "fflib_SObjectSelector" class

```
global fflib_QueryFactory addQueryFactorySubselect(fflib_QueryFactory parentQueryFactory)
{
    return addQueryFactorySubselect(parentQueryFactory, true);
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Is ev_QueryFactory is a subtype of fflib__QueryFactory? It seems that your user-defined type ev_QueryFactory is not valid type for this method addQueryFactorySubselect(fflib__QueryFactory parentQueryFactory)

Comment: Hi Eduard, we have replaced "fflib" with "ev". So you can ignore that, I have edited the question. The issue still persists ,  thank you for your time

Comment: Why does your code above have both single and double underscores in the name of the type? (`fflib_QueryFactory` vs `fflib__QueryFactory`) The signature in your `ev_SObjectSelector` class doesn't match the type you're showing in the `selectByIdWithLineItems` method.

Comment: hi Mark, it was typo from replacing "ev_" with "fflib_"  I have corrected that in question above. Why would it complain about method signature?

Answer (score 2):

Your method

```
public List<Opportunity> selectByIdWithLineItems(Set<Id> recordIds){
      fflib_QueryFactory query = newQueryFactory();
      query.setCondition('Id IN :recordIds');
      query.addQueryFactorySubselect( 
         new OpportunityLineItemsSelector().newQueryFactory() 
      );
      return (List<Opportunity>) Database.query( query.toSOQL() );
   }
```

Option 1: should look like this to include subqueries (gives you option to decide on subquery fields)

```
public List<Opportunity> selectByIdWithLineItems(Set<Id> recordIds){
      if (recordIds.isEmpty()) return new list<Opportunity>(); // avoid burning SOQL
      fflib_QueryFactory oQf = newQueryFactory()
                                .setCondition('Id IN :recordIds');

      fflib_QueryFactory oliQueryFactory = oQF.subselectQuery('OpportunityLineItems')
                .selectFields(new OpportunityLineItemsSelector().getSobjectFieldList()); 

      return Database.query(oQf.toSOQL() );
   }
```

Option 2: or should should look like this ([see example in fflib github](https://github.com/financialforcedev/fflib-apex-common-samplecode/blob/master/fflib-sample-code/src/classes/OpportunitiesSelector.cls?ts=4)) - unconditionally get all subquery fields

```
public List<Opportunity> selectByIdWithLineItems(Set<Id> recordIds){
      if (recordIds.isEmpty()) return new list<Opportunity>(); // avoid burning SOQL
      fflib_QueryFactory oQF = newQueryFactory()
                                .setCondition('Id IN :recordIds');

      fflib_QueryFactory oliQF = new OpportunityLineItemsSelector().
            addQueryFactorySubselect(oQF,'OpportunityLineItems');

      return Database.query(oQF.toSOQL() );
   }
```

Comment: Thank you cropredy, I like the option 1. To add Ordering or Where clause, I can do 

fflib_QueryFactory oliQueryFactory = oQF.subselectQuery('OpportunityLineItems')
                .selectFields(new OpportunityLineItemsSelector().getSobjectFieldList()).
.setCondition(whereClause)
                  .addOrdering(o);

This is all good. But instead of me defining that here, I would like user to pass me fflib_QueryFactory for sub query which I can then add to oQF. Any idea how I can do that?

Comment: Your exact issue - I'm not sure, never did that and Selector pattern design doesn't call for dynamically passing in queryFactories to aid in building up a selector. I'd post your requirement as an Issue in the fflib GitHub.